Ignore loading app local secrets files in CI/CD
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Web API using a local secrets management approach. In my code, two lines of code load secret files that didn't get pushed to the remote Github repo:
public static void AddSecrets(this IServiceCollection services,
    ConfigurationManager config, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    config.AddJsonFile("appsecrets.json");
    config.AddJsonFile($"appsecrets.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json");
}

The problem is when running the integration tests in CI/CD using GitHub Actions this code will throw FileNotFoundException exception because those files aren't pushed to the repo and hence don't exist.
For WebAppicationFactory side, I can only override it and there is no way I can stop running this code.
For the source code side:

Solution 1: a bad code that checks if the code is running under testing or not and I am even not sure if something like that is possible when running integration tests using WebAppicationFactory.
Solution 2: make loading files optional using optional: true but this will violate the app startup requirements.

So the question: is my secret management approach wrong from the beginning? If not how can I solve this problem?

You could create those files during the workflow execution, according to each environment, using github repository secrets, before running the application for your integration tests.

They are application-specific secret files. But you give me the idea of creating dummy empty files with the same names in the workflow.

It shouldn't be a problem those secrets being specific to the application, or do you have more than one application in your repository? Anyway, as you can even save a different secret for each environment file in the repository using the environment secret in your workflow, it wouldn't even matter here, you would just have to create a different secret for each app in your repository.

Yes. I see your point now. I tried your approach and used create-json action to generate my secret files and put them into the publish output directory and worked excellently. You can submit your answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Your approaches aren't wrong, but as GitHub Actions allows you to create environment files during the workflow execution, it may be easier to resolve your issue that way.
You can use GitHub repository secrets to generate your files according to each environment, before running the application for your integration tests.
I'll share here some references that might help:

How do I use an env file with GitHub Actions
Github Actions: Use secret file
Write Secrets to File (GitHub Community)

